# Best host for running large mem and processor intensive WordPress sites?

Tags: database, hosting

I host a number of WordPress sites, some of which have VERY large databases. I've gone through several popular web hosts though no joy yet. Any suggestions.

Comment: So what hosts didn't work out? So we don't waste time making suggestions? And are you talking about shared hosts or VPSs?

Comment: I've marked this community wiki as it has no definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a lot of hosts with tons of databases, perhaps it's time to upgrade to a dedicated server?  I host with Liquid Web and have been VERY happy.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're looking for, I'd suggest http://hub.org. It's not necessarily the cheapest around, nor does it necessarily have the most cutting edge control panel. But you get a VPS maintained by the most proficient system admin I can name (he's one of the original four behind postgresql), and it's an actual managed VPS (in the sense that whatever is not in the control panel, meaning much about everything except domain and email management, ends up as a "can you please do..." kind of support ticket). Highly recommended.